# Firebase Database onDataChange not working sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure:

```
"notifications" : {
"-KxoRpDJw6qt4kb1d4Ad" : {
  "11B Boys" : {
    "-L5QX6mvUI7Eed_FDK8R" : {
      "body" : "hello",
      "sender" : "h0ClA5VusLZMTDR6iyI4OAjLzm43",
      "title" : "hi"
    }
  },
  "All" : {
    "-L5QB_D6n_G8B5si5zMd" : {
      "body" : "d5d5",
      "sender" : "h0ClA5VusLZMTDR6iyI4OAjLzm43",
      "title" : "d5f6"
    },
    "-L5QBj31bF5On3xOIiM9" : {
      "body" : "hfhfy",
      "sender" : "h0ClA5VusLZMTDR6iyI4OAjLzm43",
      "title" : "gdgdhc"
    }
  }
```

my problem that onDataChange returns first block of notifications correctly ( messesge with "hello" body and "hi" title) other messages are not returned well (their keys are returned successfully) but it seems that they are considered as null .

heres the code:

```
           final String notificationDetails[] = token.split(";");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tvTitle.setText(dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class));
                tvBody.setText(dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue(String.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } ;
                                                                    // school_id->topic->notification_id
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications").child(notificationDetails[0]).child(notificationDetails[1])
    .child(notificationDetails[2]).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the query you're performing.

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Comment: show a screenshot of the firebase database.....

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury https://gyazo.com/3ad3618eb2a914fbc0a82f38415a22c3

Comment: Okey, i got it, remove the `child(notificationDetails[2])` from the reference because you need to listen to changes in '11B Grade'  to retrieve all the changes made to it. Currently you are listening to a child of '11B Grade'.

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury please check my answer , i'm using valueEventListener not childEventListener I think no need of removing it

Comment: but you said you have a problem in retrieval.....! your answer doesn't address something that is related with retrieval but storing the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer my self, I don't know why but when inserting entries using setValue() i must send the whole node one time.

Inserting:

```
ref.setValue(obj); // of type notification
```

Instead of:

```
ref.child("title").setValue("my title");
ref.child("body").setValue("my body");
```

Comment: That would make sense: the listener will trigger for each call to `setValue()`. After that first call, only `title` will be set.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `child(notificationDetails[2])` from the reference because you need to listen to changes in '11B Grade'  to retrieve all the changes made to it. Currently you are listening to a child of '11B Grade'.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications").child(notificationDetails[0]).child(notificationDetails[1]). addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```